# Dos batch script error? Error occurred while processing: .exe

Tags: batch-file, dos, properties-file

In a DOS script that I wrote, I am unable to figure out what causes this error that I get:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: .exe.
```

Here is the script.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried to ask for help on the DosTips forum but I am getting no answer. :

```
@echo off
:: script to edit property files
CALL :PROPEDIT # Key4 Value446 test.properties    
GOTO :END    
:PROPEDIT [#] PropKey PropVal File
IF "%~1"=="#" (
  :: Passing a first argument of "#" will disable the line while editing
  SET "_PREFIX=#"
  SHIFT
)
IF NOT "%~4"=="" (
  ECHO Too many arguments.
  EXIT /B 1
)  
IF "%~3"=="" (
  ECHO PROPEDIT: Function requires 3 args: [#] PropKey PropVal File
  EXIT /B 1
) ELSE (
  SET "_PROPKEY=%~1"
  SET "_PROPVAL=%~2"
  SET "_FILE=%~3"
)
MOVE /Y "%_FILE%" "%_FILE%.bak">nul
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%_FILE%.bak" ^|FINDSTR /N /I "%_PROPKEY%="`) DO (
  SET LINE=%%A
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%S IN ("%LINE%") DO SET LINE=%%S
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /F "USEBACKQ delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE "%_FILE%.bak" ^|FIND /V /N ""`) DO (
  SET "LN=%%A"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "LN=!LN:*]=!"
  IF "!COUNT!" NEQ "%LINE%" (
      ECHO(!LN!>>%_FILE%
  ) ELSE (
      ECHO %_PREFIX%%_PROPKEY%=%_PROPVAL%>>%_FILE%
      ECHO Updated '%_FILE%' with value '%_PREFIX%%_PROPKEY%=%_PROPVAL%'.
  )
  ENDLOCAL
  SET /A COUNT+=1
)
EXIT /B 0
:END
ECHO --- Finished Test ---
pause
```

Comment: What does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: You should explain in a few phrases what this script is doing. Also you really should add comments in your code. Is there a linenumber for the error you get?

Comment: @Tom you must be crazy :)  Batch script debugging is about as painful as it gets.  The error you see in the grey box above is probably all the OP is seeing.  It is a terrible experience.  Which is why understanding what the script is supposed to do is so important.  Also I recommend powershell if you can do it.

Comment: Tom, there are no line numbers in batch file errors. You can, of course, remove `echo off` to see where it happens but alas, no one does it. Where would be fun be in figuring out a random error in a wall of code for us, then? :) – (edited to add, this is quite clean code as far as batch files go, so leaving out the obvious debugging step surprises me actually).

Comment: It seems that I'm not used to batch files anymore ^^ @linuxuser27 the purpose of the code makes it easier for me to read the code. I don't have to read and comprehend every line of the code (or run it) to discover the error. But this is just me...

Comment: The script will run "as-is" if you just copy it to your machine and run it.  Then you will see the error that I explained above. I've seen this error a few times in the past.  I suspect it is related to delayed expansion but I am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the .EXE of FIND and TYPE

You don't need **TYPE**. You can do just this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (`FIND /N /I "%_PROPKEY%=" "%_FILE%.bak"`) DO (
```

If **FIND** spoils your results (by not using **TYPE**) then consider using **FINDSTR** instead and use '**DELIMS=:**' instead of '**DELIMS=]**'

If I'm right my assumption that the following is helpful, take a look at the '**MORE +nnn**' command (note the '**+nnn**' which outputs lines from a specific location in the file).

Why not just place your '**SETLOCAL ENABLE..** etc' at the top of your code?

If you explain what it is you're trying to attempt, then I might be in a better position to help.

Just a few thoughts :)

Comment: Thanks mucho.  I tried all those things.  SETLOCAL is in its specific location for a reason to make the function work correctly.  Also, I am trying to avoid SETLOCAL except in areas of code where its necessary because i want to reuse this function in other scripts.  I'll update my question with your suggestions but it doesn't solve the issues.

Comment: Ok, you were right.  It had something to do with the SETLOCAL.  I will post the working code as a extra answer below.

Comment: Actually, `FIND` *is* an executable, so it should be valid to call it as `find.exe`. But `type` is an internal command, so no `type.exe`, just `type`, well spot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code after getting some help from Paul Tomasi:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CALL :PROPEDIT # Key4 Value446 test.properties
GOTO :END
:PROPEDIT [#] PropKey PropVal File
IF "%~1"=="#" (
  :: Passing a first argument of "#" will disable the line while editing
  SET "_PREFIX=#"
  SHIFT
)
IF NOT "%~4"=="" (
  ECHO Too many arguments.
  EXIT /B 1
)  
IF "%~3"=="" (
  ECHO PROPEDIT: Function requires 3 args: [#] PropKey PropVal File
  EXIT /B 1
) ELSE (
  SET "_PROPKEY=%~1"
  SET "_PROPVAL=%~2"
  SET "_FILE=%~3"
)
MOVE /Y "%_FILE%" "%_FILE%.bak">nul
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "%_FILE%.bak" ^|FINDSTR /N /I "%_PROPKEY%="`) DO (
  SET LINE=%%A
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%S IN ("%LINE%") DO SET LINE=%%S
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /F "USEBACKQ delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE "%_FILE%.bak" ^|FIND /V /N ""`) DO (
  SET "LN=%%A"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "LN=!LN:*]=!"
  IF "!COUNT!" NEQ "%LINE%" (
      ECHO(!LN!>>%_FILE%
  ) ELSE (
      ECHO %_PREFIX%%_PROPKEY%=%_PROPVAL%>>%_FILE%
      ECHO Updated '%_FILE%' with value '%_PREFIX%%_PROPKEY%=%_PROPVAL%'.
  )
  SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET /A COUNT+=1
)
EXIT /B 0
:END
ECHO --- Finished Test ---
pause
```